# Guardar datos de un Array contenido en un Case para utilizarlo en otro

Tags: c#, array, switch

Soy nuevo en la programación y me encuentro trabajando con C#

Estoy trabajando con estructuras datos, y estructura condicional, precisamente con un switch, el problema es que necesito que un array que creé dentro de un case pueda utilizarlo dentro de otro case para poder operarlo y compararlo, el método funciona en case 1, pero al pasar a case 2 es como si los datos introducidos al array se limpiaran y todos me aparecen en 0.

Este es mi código:

```
case 1:
                        Console.Write("Introduzca el numero de retiros: ");
                        CantidadRetiros = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());


                        ArrayRetiros = new double[(int)CantidadRetiros];
                        MetodoMontoRetiros(ArrayRetiros);

                        Console.Clear();

                        Console.WriteLine("\n--------------------RETIROS EFECTUADOS--------------------\n");

                        PrintRetiros(ArrayRetiros);
                        Console.WriteLine("Presione ENTER para continuar...");
                        break;

------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------                    
//Metodos                

                void MetodoMontoRetiros(double[] arr1)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < CantidadRetiros; i++)
                    {
                        Console.Write("Introduzca el monto del retiro #" + (i + 1) + ": ");
                        arr1[i] = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                    }
                }

                void PrintRetiros(double[] arr2)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < CantidadRetiros; i++)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Retiro #" + (i + 1) + ": $" + arr2[i] + "\n");
                    }
                }
```

Me recomendaron hacer funciones y no he podido aplicarlas adecuadamente.
Gracias de antemano.

Comment: de que array hablas?

Comment: Faltan slgunos detalles, como por ejemplo desde donde invocas los métodos, donde están esos métodos, donde está el switch.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! te sugiero que revises tu pregunta.. tiene un monton de problemas por lo cual es imposible darte una respuesta....

Comment: Coloca el código completo, porque con lo que has puesto no se puede identificar el problema. Pero te voy mencionando que una variable creada en un case solo pertenece a ese ámbito, no pudiendo ser accedida desde afuera.

Answer (score 1):

Te voy a responder, suponiendo que lo tengas todo en la misma clase, y llames a los métodos desde el Main

La solución que te propongo, es crear el array en el método y una vez rellenado, devolverlo nuevamente desde donde fué llamado

```
//método main
public static void Main(String[] args)
    {
        //declaramos una variable entera para el ejemplo
        int decision = 0;
        //declaramos tu variable double
        double CantidadRetiros;

        //pedimos el número del case para el ejemplo
        Console.Write("Introduzca el valor del case: ");
        //usamos la variable decision para el ejemplo
        decision = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        //hacemos un condicional con solo tu ejemplo
        switch (decision)
        {
            //si entramos en el primer case
            case 1:
                //pedimos el número de retiros
                Console.Write("Introduzca el numero de retiros: ");
                //capturamos los retiros en la variable double 
                CantidadRetiros = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

                //llamamos al método para introducir los valores de los retiros y enviamos la cantidad de retiros por parámetro.
                /el método nos retornará el arrayRetiros
                double[] arrayRetiros = MetodoMontoRetiros(CantidadRetiros);

                Console.Clear();

                //imprimimos en pantalla el texto y damos una línea en blanco
                Console.WriteLine("\n--------------------RETIROS EFECTUADOS--------------------\n");

                //llamamos al método para imprimir el array y se lo enviamos por parámetro
                PrintRetiros(arrayRetiros);

                Console.WriteLine("Presione ENTER para continuar...");
                break;
        }

    }
    //Metodos                
    //método para crear y llenar el array que recibe la cantidad de resgistros a ingresar
    private static double[] MetodoMontoRetiros(double CantidadRetiros)
    {
        //declaramos el array con el límete de la cantidad dada
        double[] arrayRetiros = new double[(int)CantidadRetiros];

        for (int i = 0; i < arrayRetiros.Length; i++)
        {
            //vamos pidiendo los datos de cada retiro
            Console.Write("Introduzca el monto del retiro #" + (i + 1) + ": ");
            //almacenamos el dato capturado del teclado en la posición del array correspondiente a la iteración del bucle
            arrayRetiros[i] = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        }
        //retornamos el array
        return arrayRetiros;
    }
    //método que imprimer el array que recibe por parámetro
    private static void PrintRetiros(double[] arr2)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < arr2.Length; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Retiro #" + (i + 1) + ": $" + arr2[i] + "\n");
        }
    }
```

Tu pregunta es tan abierta, que deja infinidad de soluciones o posibilidades.

También podrías declarar el arrayList a nivel de clase y tenerlo visible por todos los métodos, teniendo en cuenta que el arrayList no necesita saber el número de registros que contendrá y resulta mucho más versátil.